# Do you get the same performance using index prefixes?

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

Say I have a collection containing documents like the one below:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(),
   myValue: 123,
   otherValue: 456
}
```

I then create like below:

```
{myValue: 1, otherValue: 1}
```

If I execute the following query:

```
db.myCollection.find({myValue: 123})
```

will I get the same performance with my index as I would if I have an index on **only** the `myValue` field?  Or is the performance degraded some how since it is using an [index Prefix](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#compound-index-prefix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ["compound index"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#compound-index-prefix) which is the correct term for your "link" does not create any performance problems on "read" ( since writing new entries is obviously more information ) than an index just on the single field used in the query. With one exception.

If you use a ["multi-Key"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/) index which means an "array" item as part of the index then you effectively create `n` more items in the index per key. As in:

```js
{ "a": 1, "b": [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

An index on `{ "a": 1, "b": 1 }` means this in basic terms:

```js
{ "a": 1, "b": 1 },
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 },
{ "a": 1, "b": 3 }
```

So basically one index entry per array element to be scanned.

But otherwise the single element does not affect performance with the general exclusion of the "obvious" need to load a structure that contains more data than what you "need to use" into memory per element.

So if you don't need it then don't use it. And creating "two" indexes ( one for compound one for single field ) might save you memory, but it will "cost" you in write performance and storage space in general.

Comment: Excellent answer - thanks!  Just to clarify, Index Prefixes are a concept that exist within compound indexes.  It has to do with index usage - so while compound indexes and prefixes are related they are not the same thing.

Comment: @AbeMiessler The general case with a "compound index" in MongoDB is that you want to use the "first" element of that compound index in any query that uses any of the elements but not necessarily all of them.  So that was my point to clarify what you said. If you don't call the "first" element in the index then it will not be used.